# "Catch all other" Firebase database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Perhaps I'm tackling this problem too much from an SQL kind of perspective, but I'm having troubles understanding how to properly restrict which children should be allowed to populate a node.

Say that I want to keep a record of products with arbitrary names. Each product must contain a `price`, but nothing else is allowed.

My naive approach was to add a `.validate` rule to the products requiring newData to contain a `price` child, explicitly granting write access to the `price` node and then removing all access an `$other` node (somewhat like a default clause in a switch statement):

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$product": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['price'])",
            "price": {
                ".write": true,
                ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
            },
            "$other": {
                ".read.": false,
                ".write": false,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work. Adding a new product with `{"price": 1234, "foo": "bar"}` will still be accepted. <del>If I however add a `".validate": false` rule to `$other`, nothing is accepted instead (e.g. `{"price": 1234}` is not allowed).</del> *(I did that wrong, somehow.)*

Is there some way to implement something similar to what I'm trying to do here? If not, what is the proper way of restricting a data structure in Firebase? Should I do it at all? What stops the user from filling my database with trash if I don't?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why `"$other": { ".validate": false }` is not what you want. However, disregarding that, are you aware that you cannot revoke a permission once granted? So the `".write": true` under `$product` means your `".write": false` under `$other` is ignored?

Comment: @cartant I updated the question to clarify why validate doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're falling into a few common Firebase security pits here. The most common one is that permission cascades down: once you've granted read or write permission on a certain level in the tree, you cannot take that permission away at a lower level.

That means that these rules are ineffectual (since you've *granted* read/write one level higher already):

```
"$other": {
    ".read.": false,
    ".write": false,
}
```

To solve the problem you must realize that `.validate` rules are different: data is only considered valid when *all* validation rules are met. So you can reject the `$other` data with a validation rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$product": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['price'])",
            "price": {
                ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
            },
            "$other": {
                ".validate": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves it. The funny thing is that I thought I had tried this very solution (like I briefly mentioned in the question), but apparently I managed to botch that up somehow. Either way, your answer also made the differences between validate and write much clearer to me so thank you for that. :)

Comment: How would this look in bolt?