# Firebase Security - Write Permission Hierarchy Inquiry

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've read that the `write` permission present in the parent node is valid for all children nodes. So if in the parent node I use the rule `".write": true` and in the child node I use the rule `".write": false`, the second rule is invalid.

But I see that if I write this rule schema:

```
"test": {
      ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() != null && auth.uid == null",
      "$test":{
        ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() != null && auth.uid != null"
      }
    }
```

In the child node, it is valid only to the rule of the child node, because it's possible to create this node by an authenticated user. While in the parent, I permit the `write` action only for the non-authtenticated users.

For me this is a useful thing but I think that it doesn't match with the description of the `write` function.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: it seems that this working does not match with the description of the write function. I would like more clarification about it. because in this case seems that the parent rule not work for the child

Comment: The key point is that once you grant a permission for a parent, you cannot revoke it for a child. With your rules, both authenticated and unauthenticated users can write new values under `$test`. What is it that needs to be clarified?

Comment: ok this point. then the rules of the second write, are added to the first?

Comment: No. ["... permission cascades down: once you've granted read or write permission on a certain level in the tree, you cannot take that permission away at a lower level."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39082962/6680611)

Comment: yes i know this thing, but you have write, "With your rules, both authenticated and unauthenticated users can write new values under $test". in this case seems like a cascade because the second auth is in a different write

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122677/discussion-between-dthink-and-cartant).