# Firebase Rules to set read/write on specific property

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am storing a data set of homeless/emergency shelters in firebase. All the data should be read: true, and write: false except for OCCUPANCY property which I would like to be write: true. I have been trying a couple of things based on other stack overflow posts (including: [this post using $other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082513/catch-all-other-firebase-database-rule)) but have not been able to make it work. I was hopeful the following code would work, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
 "rules": {
     ".read": true,
        "locations": {
            "$location": {
                OCCUPANCY": {
                    ".read": true,
                    ".write": true
                    },
                $other": {
                    ".read": true,
                    ".write": false
                    }
                }
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have run this in the firebase simulator and it seems to work as required, however on the website it consoles `Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied`

[image]

THE PROBLEM: The code sending the update to firebase was also updating two other parameters. If part of the update does not permission to write all of it fails.

THE SOLUTION: Update firebase rules to allow write for those parameters, remove redundant read statements from nested parameters (as suggested below).

```
  {
   "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       "locations": {
            "$location": {
                "OCCUPANCY": {
                    ".write": true
                    },
                "time": {
                    ".write": true
                    },
                "updated": {
                    ".write": true
                },     
                    "$other": {
                    ".write": false
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First things I notice: once you have `".read": true` on the top-level, all the lower level `.read` rules are meaningless. It seems unrelated to your question, but I'd recommend fixing it in your rules anyway.

Comment: Aside from that: please update your question with the code that fails. I recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for information on how and why.

Comment: Thanks for the replies... I was so focused on the firebase rules I forgot that two other parameters were being sent in in addition to the "OCCUPANCY". If it can't update one if permission is denied to any of the updates.